# Scala-Is there another way to write this foreach method?

Tags: scala, recursion, foreach, functional-programming

I have this case class with the foreach method:

```
case class Sequence[A](initialElems: A*) {
  private val elems = ArrayBuffer[A]()

  elems ++= initialElems

  @tailrec
  final def foreach(block: A => Unit, elems: ArrayBuffer[A] = elems): Unit = elems.size match {
    case 0 =>
    case _  =>
      block(elems.head)
      foreach(block, elems.tail)
  }
}
```

But it feels weird to me, is there another, more simple and efficient way to write it?

Comment: Could you elaborate what "feels weird" to you?

Comment: @yuval-itzchakov The case 0 =>, leaving it empty. Maybe it is correct but I think it has to be another way to write the end of the recursion.

Comment: You don't have to leave the case block empty. You could put in `()` (empty parentheses) which is a value (the only value) of type `Unit`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you intended to use this class? It might help us to understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you want a recursive function at all when you can use the existing `foreach` method:

```
case class Sequence[A](initialElems: A*) {
  private val elems = ArrayBuffer[A](initialElems:_*)

  final def foreach(block: A => Unit, elems: ArrayBuffer[A] = elems): Unit =
    elems.foreach(block)
}
```

It is also odd to be able to pass in the `elems` value. If you do pass in a value then this method does not use any of the class data, which means it doesn't really need to be a method.

Finally, it is usual to put the `block` as the final parameter group so that it can be used in a more natural way, like this:

```
case class Sequence[A](initialElems: A*) {
  private val elems = ArrayBuffer[A](initialElems:_*)

  final def foreach(elems: ArrayBuffer[A])(block: A => Unit): Unit = elems.foreach(block)
  final def foreach(block: A => Unit): Unit = elems.foreach(block)
}

val s = Sequence(1,2,3)

s.foreach{ e =>
  println(e)
}
```

Comment: But that existing foreach method isn't a pure function, isn't it? I am trying to build it pure, and in order to make it tail recursive I pass the elems parameter. Also I need to wrap the method inside the case class in order to wirte for comprehensions.

Comment: Your `foreach` method is as *impure* as stdlib `foreach`. `A => Unit` is a side-effectful function, so there is no way to implement a method which uses it *purely*.